# How to get the value id of the link in php

Tags: php, html, css

Well this is my first time to ask question in this website so please someone help me with this.

I want to show the information of my customers information by clicking there names in the table and when i click it i want to see the information in a modal. And this is my code

```php
<?php
include 'config.php';
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM appliancesrep") or die(mysqli_error());
echo "<tbody>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td>' .$row['descr']. '</td>';
  echo '<td>' .$row['model']. '</td>';
  echo '<td>' .$row['brand']. '</td>';
  echo '<td>' .$row['purchased']. '</td>';
  echo  limit($row['problem'],20);
$str = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from customer WHERE id =" . $row['id']);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($str)){
echo '<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"href="'.$row['fname'].$row['mname'] . $row['lname']. '" value="' .$row['id']. '">' .$row['fname']."".$row['mname']." " .$row['lname'].  '</a></td>';
echo "<div class='modal fade' id='exampleModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel'>
<div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
<div class='modal-content'>
<div class='modal-body'>
<form>
<div class='form-group'>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>Name:</label>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label' value='" .$row['id']. "'>" .$row['fname']." ".$row['mname']." " .$row['lname']. "</label></div>
<div class='form-group'>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>Gender:</label>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>".$row['gender']."</label>
</div>
</form>
<div class='modal-footer'>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tbody>";
?>
```

And when i first try it in the first customer's named Rick the output is ok but when i click another customer's named John the Rick's information will come up and not for John and i noticed that when i always click the modal my web page container's width is getting smaller.

Well i finally figure out the information thing and this is my code..

```html
$str = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from customer WHERE id =" . $row['id']);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($str)){
echo '<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id']. '">' .$row['fname']."".$row['mname']." " .$row['lname'].  '</a></td>';
echo "<div class='modal fade' id='".$row['id']."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel'>
<div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
<div class='modal-content'>
<div class='modal-body'>
<form>
<div class='form-group'>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>Name:</label>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label' value='" .$row['id']. "'>" .$row['fname']." ".$row['mname']." " .$row['lname']. "</label></div>
<div class='form-group'>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>Gender:</label>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>".$row['gender']."</label>
</div>
</form>
<div class='modal-footer'>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tbody>";
?>
```

I only change the data-target of the link and the id of the modal now my only problem is that every time i click my modal the width of my container is getting smaller is it because of the  tag???

Comment: Why `value` attribute for `a`? Why the `href` attribute only contains the name?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class='modal-footer'>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>";
}
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tbody>";
```

put a code "; behind last div tag and rectify the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model Body is not properly closed.
Its should be :

```
<div class='modal-body'>
<form>
<div class='form-group'>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>Name:</label>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label' value='" .$row['id']. "'>" .$row['fname']." ".$row['mname']." " .$row['lname']. "</label></div>
<div class='form-group'>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>Gender:</label>
<label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>".$row['gender']."</label>
</div>
</form>
</div> <!-- modal-body -->
```